Installing Ubuntu Into VM workstation
I want to install Ubuntu into VM workstation on a virtual machine to do my senior project, however when I reached the installation options, I see 2 options, as shown in the image below:
1- Erase disk and install Ubuntu
2- Manual installation
I am concerned about selecting the wrong option and potentially losing my computer's operating system "Windows" and lose all of my data.
Could someone guide me which option i should choose?
Thank you.
Options image

Related: Will erasing the disk on VirtualBox erase all the other operating systems i have installed on VirtualBox
